# Placing an extra empty linebreak in the Redactor Field

Tags: richtext, redactor

I've been trying to add extra line breaks to a text field, But this seems impossible?

Most logical thing to do for the user would be to give it an extra linebreak `<br>`

Those get deleted, sometimes directly, sometimes after opening and then saving again

So far I've tried:

- disable cleanup html in the field - still deletes `<br>`

In the json file settings:

- tidyHtml: false - no
- cleanSpaces: false - no
- removeEmptyTags: false - no
- linebreaks: true - this converts ALL breaks to line breaks. Not handy.

Comment: Noregt, why would you want to do this? This is considered as bad practice, you won't even know how a browser interprets it actually.

Comment: IGNORE that comment, I first thought you want to produce several line breaks like so: `<br><br>`! Better don't do that, but a single `<br>` is totally legitimate.

Comment: Yes that is, but it is erased every time. Furthermore it is the wish/demand of my client and he is not the first one to ask this.

Comment: Don't forget to tell the client to only use it (in those rather rare situations) where it is actually appropriate. Once they learned it, they may not use a normal "paragraph" <enter> again :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried this again in Craft 2.3 and now it works as most people would expect (I know, not as it should for html purists)

Shift Enter = `<br>`

Regular Enters are coded as `<p><br></p>`, forcing an empty line. For me, this works :-)

This is with 'Clean HTML' selected and HTML purifier OFF

Comment: Glad to see you got your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

For me this works: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Well does it still if you open and then save it again without editing?

Comment: Sure. In web apps it's <Shift>+<Enter> and OS X apps it's <Alt>+<Enter>.

Comment: It also works if you copy and paste line breaks from other apps. They appear and get saved in the Redactor field as expected.

Comment: Sorry but my point is that that does not work. I'm aware that you can make a line break '<br>' with Shift Enter. If I make two of those the first save one is left, the second save both are gone.

Comment: It works for me, @noregt. Manually adding `<br>`does not though.

Comment: Just tried it again, @noregt! Still works on my install, no matter how many of them I make or how often I save the entry!

Comment: I'll try it with a different install. Maybe it's something specific then. I'll have to test it.

Comment: Yep. I just tested it for you on another install (long time untouched and still on 1.3) and it worked there, too. Good luck, @noregt!

Comment: Not working for me on a bare Craft install...

Comment: @Marion yes I also noticed that multiple `<br>` only work with older versions of Craft / Redactor.

Answer (score 0):

**Single Line-Break**

To insert a [line-break `<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) into a Redactor text field use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard.

Do this for single [line-breaks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) only! You or your client should not misuse the `<br>` tag for  styling purposes by adding multiple of them in a row. It is semantically wrong (and you can't be sure how browsers interpret it).

With older versions of Redactor / Craft it was possible to do this. I can still save Redactor fields with `<br><br><br>` on a Craft 1.3 installation, but something must have changed down the road, because now all but one gets removed.

But there's other ways to make adding vertical space within a Redactor field possible:

**Horizontal Line**

If it matches the semantic meaning of that space you create, what about using a [horizontal line `<hr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr) instead and style it to your needs:

```
hr {
  height: 3em;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Redactor has a build-in button for `<hr>`. Edit your [Redactor configs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/rich-text-fields#redactor-configs) for it to show up:

```
{
    buttons: [
        'html','formatting','bold','italic',
        'unorderedlist','orderedlist','link','image','video',
        'horizontalrule'
    ],
    plugins: ['fullscreen'],
    toolbarFixedBox: true
}
```

**DIV**

That vertical space should not have any semantic meaning at all and you simply want an option to insert some beautiful white space? Then it gets a bit more complicated, because what you should add to your markup in this case is a sematically meaningless element, a `div` or `span`.

To do this, switch to "HTML Mode" in your Redactor field and add an empty `div` inbetween your paragraphs:

```
<p>
        More white space for these paragraphs, please!
</p>
<div class="whitespace"><div>
<p>
        More white space for these paragraphs, please!
</p>
```

You have to configure Redactor to not convert `div` on save by setting `convertDivs:false`. (note that this setting [will be renamed to `replaceDivs`](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/whats-new-10/) with Redactor 10).

To make inserting such `div` easier, write you own little Craft / Redactor plugin that inserts the HTML with the click on a button and add some CSS to style your white space on the backend. A good starting point for the JS might be the ["Insert HTML" Redactor plugin](http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/insert-html/).

The [Craft plugin "RedactorClips"](http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/insert-html/) could be an alternative, but I think there's no option to set custom CSS for the backend.

Comment: The [RedactorClips](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorClips) plugin mysteriously fails to add the clip. I can't get [RedactorStyles](https://github.com/aelvan/RedactorStyles-Craft/) to add the div either, but it does have a way to set the backend CSS.

Comment: Yeah, I behaves strange for me too if I add the whitespace clip within a paragraph. Did work though in a new paragraph: hit enter and then add the clip. But as I wrote, it's probably better to write a custom plugin (incl. backend CSS). What about using a `hr`? Doesn't fit your needs, @Marion?

Comment: It's not semantic whitespace, so not `hr`. Best I came up with is a paragraph with a spacer `img`. That `div` is definitely better.